# How to Read data from rows and column wise in Excel sheet using Shell Script and login to browser?

Tags: excel, linux, bash

For automating access credentials, I have access keys in Excel file in some location. now I need to read password keys in rows and columns from this file using shell script and login to a specific website. can someone help me with this?

Thanks & Regards
Francis

Answer (score 0):

A MS-Excel file is a binary file. You need a particular tool to open it, e.g. MS-Excel.

Or, you can program using some module/library to handle office files, like java,Perl or python, and then call your program in a shell script. [How to read excel file in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522973/how-to-read-excel-file-in-shell-script)

You can, however, turn it into a text file, E.g. csv, so that some command-line text processing tool can read from it, for example, awk.

To login to a website, or call some REST endpoint you may make use of curl.

Answer (score 0):

#### Read file

You can using `libreoffice` to read xls or xlsx file, and convert to csv file.

```sh
# it will generate a same name csv file
libreoffice --headless --convert-to csv foo.xlsx
```

#### Get nth row

```sh
# Get 10th line of foo.csv (row 10)
CSV=$(cat foo.csv | sed -n "10p")
```

#### Parse csv file

And you can parse the csv file, there are have several way to do.
`csvtool`, `regex`, ...etc.

Here is regex way. Format `grep -oP <regex>`

```sh
CSV='9,"foo,bar",12'

regex='(?:,|^)("(?:(?:"")*[^"]*)*"|[^",]*)'
matches=$(echo $CSV | grep -oP $regex)
echo "$matches"

# 9
# ,"foo,bar"
# ,12
```

I'm not sure why match include comma, but it can remove easily.

The rest is up to you.